# Wampp Server not turn to green

Tags: mysql, wamp

I have installed Easy ID VPN. After uninstalling Easy Hide VPN and deleting EasyDirect64.dll my wampp server stop working and not turn into green. The mysql.log file is something like this. I'm using phpmyadmin for this

> 2017-08-19T09:44:02.953235Z 0 [ERROR] Fails to print out IP-address.
>   2017-08-19T09:44:02.953235Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to create a socket for
>   IPv4 '': errno: 10106. 2017-08-19T09:44:02.968808Z 0 [ERROR] Can't
>   create IP socket: No such file or directory
>   2017-08-19T09:44:02.968808Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Please help me out as I have searched a lot and not solve the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

Please Download Iobit Uninstaller and uninstall Wamp server you'll see powerful uninstall after normal uninstalling do complete powerful install. And install wamp server again.

Comment: this method not working. It is failing to create a socket at IPV4. I have uninstall Wamp many times but not working

Comment: then you need to change port number. default port Number is 80 you have change it to any other may 88 or 8080 or 8888 any free ports available

Answer (score 0):

can you please check port 80 is free or not and also let me know if skype is installed in your system because skype also uses port 80 which don't allow wamp server to run because port is already in use by skype.

Comment: yes port 80 is free, I have skype installed on my system. I also try to change skype connection setting but all in vain

Comment: simply alter the apache httpd.conf. You can access this file from the wampp menu > Apache > httpd.conf

Next alter the

#Listen **.**.**.**:80
Listen 80
To for example

#Listen **.**.**.**:88 (if this port number "88" doesn't works you can use any other port number that is free)
Listen 88
Restart wamp and services then type http://localhost:88 and you'll have wamp up and running

Comment: Actually the Main issue is Wamp Server won't change it's color from red. 
However I have also try this one but not working

Comment: are you sure you have tried different port no ???.. other then 80 and 88